# Mongo crashes when I call "mongo" in terminal

Tags: mongodb

Mongo was working just fine a day ago. Then this morning I get up and try opening up and I get this:

```
    MongoDB shell version: 2.6.4
2015-01-06T11:10:54.142-0500 SEVERE: terminate() called in shell, printing stack:
0x869641 0x61b108 0x7fb82934f836 0x7fb82934f863 0x7fb82934faa2 0x6be096 0x8ae0b8 0x7bb040 0x7a51e6 0x7a5305 0x61f09d 0x621fc3 0x7fb828a30ec5 0x61ac69
 mongo(_ZN5mongo15printStackTraceERSo+0x21) [0x869641]
 mongo(_Z11myterminatev+0x48) [0x61b108]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x5e836) [0x7fb82934f836]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x5e863) [0x7fb82934f863]
 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6(+0x5eaa2) [0x7fb82934faa2]
 mongo(_ZN5boost15throw_exceptionINS_21thread_resource_errorEEEvRKT_+0x166) [0x6be096]
 mongo(_ZN5boost6thread12start_threadEv+0x138) [0x8ae0b8]
 mongo(_ZN5mongo15DeadlineMonitorINS_7V8ScopeEEC1Ev+0x420) [0x7bb040]
 mongo(_ZN5mongo14V8ScriptEngineC1Ev+0x96) [0x7a51e6]
 mongo(_ZN5mongo12ScriptEngine5setupEv+0x45) [0x7a5305]
 mongo(_Z5_mainiPPcS0_+0x43d) [0x61f09d]
 mongo(main+0x33) [0x621fc3]
 /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xf5) [0x7fb828a30ec5]
 mongo(__gxx_personality_v0+0x469) [0x61ac69]
```

Any ideas on what this is and how I can fix it? I am using Linux.

Answer (score 1):

Turns out the system had run out of memory. After shutting down a few other applications I was able to get it up and running again. I hope if someone runs into the same problem that this helps.